# Resizing mat-form-field

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

How can I resize an entire material form? I'd like the form field to be roughly the same size as the preceding `h3` text. The default seems to render comically large. I've tried applying `size` and `font size` CSS to the `mat-form-field` element, the `mat-select` element, and the `mat-option` element without achieving the desired outcome.

[image: screenshot displaying the undesirably large mat-form-field]

---

**settings.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar class="menu_bar" color="primary">
    <h1>Configuration</h1>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-toolbar class="top-container">
    <span class="select">
        <h3>Selected Object:</h3>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-select>
                <mat-option value="object1">Object 1</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="object2">Object 2</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="object3">Object 3</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

---

**settings.component.css**

```
h1 {
    font-size: 4vh;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body {
    font-size: 2vh;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: lightgray;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.menu_bar {
    background-color: rgb(200, 213, 234);
    color: black;
}

.select {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.top-container {
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override class style in `style.css` or `style.scss`

```css
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-infix {
    padding: 0px 0 9px 0;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ud4dev?file=src%2Fstyles.scss